# Moodle authentification from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, moodle

I am using moodle 3.11, and trying to connect to a SQL Server database, as external authentication method.

The connection to the server succeeded, but I got message as shown in the screenshot: input array:false, result:Null

Also the number of users in the authentication dashboard is 0; I tried to bring the list of the users by modifying the file auth.php under the .\rootfolder\auth\db and i got all the records and the fields name, but still can't connect using this external method.

Any help it will be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does that select statement return any records? Have you tried without the `WHERE` clause? are there any records in the table?

Comment: Yes, when i change the query it works , i can see the records and the table structure also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe double check the external table and column names.

Are they exactly the same in the external database settings?

Site administration > Plugins > Authentication > External database

[image]

Also does the DB user in the settings have permission to access that table?